# How to show name of user in Facebook

Tags: facebook

Doing some search it seems like the old way to show the current user name in a Facebook page described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/userlink/

So doing something like

```
<fb:userlink uid="loggedinuser" />
```

I wonder what is the new way to do this without using fb tags. I want to show of the user even if they haven't authenticated the application.

Comment: Use the XFBML version of fb:name instead … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: @CBroe isn't XFBML deprecated as well?